# Add array object to array php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array object that looks like this and stored in a variable `$named_array`

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2013-15-6
                    [position] => 5
                    [person] => John
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2013-15-6
                    [position] => 3
                    [person] => Alex
                )

        )

)
```

Another array called `$post` which is a WordPress post object array called with `$posts = get_posts(array(....` I then have a foreach each loop with $post being the variable.

Within my foreach loop i've tried the following to combine the arrays but it's not working.

```
$combinedData = array_merge($post, $named_array);
print_r($combinedData);
```

I can see my post object arrays with print_r($post); within the foreach loop as well as the named_array. What's the correct function to add the named_array to the post array?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what you want your final array to look like. Are you trying to append each post to the "results" array?

Comment: @koala_dev I'm trying to append the results array to the post array so the post array has one nested array being "results"

Comment: You mean each post is going to have the same result array?

Comment: The results array is stored in a variable, it's dynamic not the same exact values but same keys

Comment: I see, I've added an answer that I believe is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$posts` as you mentioned, is an array of objects

`$post` is an object, not an array, so you can't use `array_merge()`

If you want to add the results as a new property to `$post`, the correct way to do it is:

```
$post->results = $named_array['results'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Can you let me know when running $post->results does this create an array in the post object called 'results' where the key's and values from the named_array['results'] are then placed. Am I basically saying what key's and values to get from the named array and which array to place them into in the other?

Comment: It's just like any other assignation code, say you have a variable `$x=1` and then you set another's variable value to $x like `$y=$x` now $y holds the same value as $x, in this case we add a new property to the $post object and set the value to the results array

Answer (score 1):

if $post is an object you can add an array called results with this

```
$post->results = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2013-15-6
                [position] => 5
                [person] => John
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2013-15-6
                [position] => 3
                [person] => Alex
            )

    )
```

or `$post->results = $named_array['results'];`

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php Try this instead of array_merge

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to use array_merge *inside* the foreach loop in this case. You use array_merge to append the second array overwriting identical keys. You use foreach for array operations that apply to each element.

You did'nt show how your $post array is looking like. So I can only guess.

```
$combinedData = array_merge ( $post, $named_array );
```

already appends the named array to $post. Maybe you wanted this?

```
array_shift ( $named_array, $post );
```

It assumes that the post array looks like one element of the named array.

Comment: If this is not what you expect please show an example of your $post array.